# What is the most accepted explanation of aurophilicity?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, elements, reference-request

Gold has a special property called aurophilicity. [Inorganic chemistry by Huheey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006042995X) has some explanation, but that was not enough to clear the conception.

Comment: Have a look at [*The aurophilicity phenomenon: A decade of experimental findings, theoretical concepts and emerging applications*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03215477) by Hubert Schmidbaur for some further directions and references.